# Python mock patch a function missing arguments

Tags: python, mocking

I have the following code in module a:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def dowork(self, value1, value2):
        print value1, value2
```

In module b:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
    value1 = ...        
    value2 = ...

    def call_manager(self):
        self.objects.dowork(self.value1, self.value2)
```

In unittest I am patching the `dowork` with a different body, such as:

```
def new_dowork(self, value1, value2):
    print 123

with patch('a.MyManager.dowork', new_callable=new_dowork):
    record = MyModel(value=111)
    record.call_manager()
    ...
```

But I am getting `TypeError: new_dowork() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much about [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html), but I think the main issue is that you should pass the mock function in the `new` argument, not in `new_callable`, and use [patch.object](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object) to actually overwrite a method within an object.

This seems to work:

```
from mock import patch

class MyManager(object):

    def dowork(self, value1, value2):
        print value1, value2

class MyModel(object):
    objects = MyManager()
    value1 = 'foo'        
    value2 = 'bar'

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        # You don't need this __init__... Is just so I don't have to 
        # use models.MyModel thingy
        pass

    def call_manager(self):
        self.objects.dowork(self.value1, self.value2)

def new_dowork(self, value1, value2):
    print "Mock called"
    print 123

with patch.object(MyManager, 'dowork', new=new_dowork):
    record = MyModel(value=111)
    record.call_manager()
```

This outputs:

```
Mock called
123
```

Comment: Cool, using `new` worked, I still seem to have trouble understand when to use `new` or `new_callable`

Comment: From the docs: _new_callable allows you to specify a different class, or callable object, that will be called to create the new object. By default MagicMock is used._ So it looks like it's used if you want to replace the default `MagicMock` "mocker" class which I'm guessing is something you'd rarely need (It seems to be trying to instantiate a class, therefore, in this particular example, ends up running your function) But this is just a guess (I don't know nearly enough about Mock to be sure of this)